# How to select the las Li with Xpath or Css Selector

Tags: xpath, css-selectors

I want to select the text in the last li with xpath, i can use Css Selector too.
here the value is "3"

```
<div class="pg">
    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="PaginationForm.CurrentPage">
    <input id="PaginationForm_TotalPage" type="hidden" value="41" name="PaginationForm.TotalPage">
    <span class="pgPrev">‹</span>
    <ul>
        <li class="">
            <span class="current">1</span>
        </li>
        <li class="">
            <a>2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
            <a>3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <a class="jsNxtPage pgNext">›</a>
</div>
```

i try this in Selenium

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('(//*[@class="pg"]/ul/li/text())[last()]')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the method name suggests, it can only return *element*, not text node. You can find the target `<a>` element first :

```
a = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="pg"]/ul/li[last()]/a')
```

And then you can get the inner text from `a.text`